# Delaying static class member initialization

Tags: python, initialization, static-members

I have this (example) code:

```
init()

class A:
    foo = bar()

    def __init__(self):
        print(A.foo)
```

The problem is, the function `bar()` refuses to work unless `init()` has been called first. What is a nice Pythonesque solution for this problem?

---

In my specific situation `init()` is third-party and can not be adapted and is called in a different file than `A` is defined.

Comment: As an aside, if you need to delay initialization until `A` is initialized, then `foo` is not really static, but rather a singleton.

Comment: Is it really necessary for foo to be a class attribute? I'm suspect you'd better off with reworking that part of the design.

Comment: Well, the class in question is a `Character` and the static attribute is `Character.sprite`. It is one common thing along all `Character` instances, and closely related so a static member aatribute seemed best. And the library I use can't load the sprite from file before the library is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
class A:
    foo = None
    def __init__(self):
        if A.foo is None:
             A.foo = bar()
        print(A.foo)
```

You could also move the `if` statement to `A.__new__()` if you are not sure `A.__init__()` will be called (e.g. when unpickling an `A` object before explicitly calling its constructor).

Comment: This is the solution I was thinking of too, but I thought there must be a better, more Pythonesque way.

Comment: As far as I understand it only saves you from getting an exception. `foo` could have `None` value for some time until `init()` is called. You also suggest binding a static variable to instance initialization.  I think a better way would be to simply add an explicit static initialization function that sets `foo = bar()`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the call to `bar()` in another function that will also ensure that `init()` has been called.

Comment: And how would any function ensure that `init()` has been called, except for calling it itself?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'refuses to work' if it throws an exception you could catch it. If it returns `None` you could check it , and so on. Need more details here. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: It throws an exception. But what could you do with it?

Comment: What do you want to happen in such situation? And if you only want to avoid this situation, can you actually make sure that the static isn't used before `init()` is called?

Comment: Not without constructs like Sven Marnach is suggesting.